# Show that for any $M \subset H$, $\hskip 2mm M \subset (M^{\perp})^{\perp}$. Also, show that if $M = (M^{\perp})^{\perp}$, then $M$ is a subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis

a. Show that for any $M \subset H$, $\hskip 2mm M \subset (M^{\perp})^{\perp}$.

b. If $M = (M^{\perp})^{\perp}$, then $M$ is a subspace.

This problem is related to another problem. Let $M = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) \in l_2, x_1+x_2=0\}$. Find $M^{\perp}$. Find the decomposition $l_2=M \oplus M^{\perp}$. For this previous problem, I think that the orthogonal subspace is $\{(c, c, 0, 0, 0, ...), \text{c is a real number}\}$. An inner product of this and any element from $M$ is $cx_1 + cx_2=c(x1+x2)=0$ since $x_1 = -x_2$.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I should have mentioned that this problem is related to another problem. Let $M = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) \in l_2, x_1+x_2=0\}$. Find $M^{\perp}$. Find the decomposition $l_2=M \oplus M^{\perp}$. For this previous problem, I think that the orthogonal subspace is $\{(c, c, 0, 0, 0, ...), \text{c is a real number}\}$. An inner product of this and any element from $M$ is $cx_1 + cx_2=c(x1+x2)=0$ since $x_1 = -x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in M$ and $y\in M^{\perp}.$ Then, by definition, $\langle x,y\rangle=0$, so $x\in (M^{\perp})^{\perp}$. This is $a)$.

For $b)$, simply observe that, for any $A\subseteq H,$ $A^{\perp}$ is a subspace. Indeed, let $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}$ and $x,y\in A^{\perp}$. Then, if $a\in A$, we see that
$$
\langle \alpha x+\beta y,a\rangle=\alpha\langle x,a\rangle+\beta\langle y,a\rangle=0,
$$
so $\alpha x+\beta y\in A^{\perp}$. Now, $b)$ is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

$(M^\perp)^\perp$ consists of all vectors that are orthogonal to $M^\perp$, which clearly includes $M$. So $M\subseteq (M^\perp)^\perp$.

The orthogonal complement $M^\perp$ of any set is a subspace because, if $x,y$ are orthogonal to $M$, then so is $\alpha x + \beta y$ by linearity of the inner product.